# how to implement an didFinishNavigation properly

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to implement a snippet of code on didFinishNavigation that calls a js function in the webview. But it seems like I did not implement this properly.

```
#import "DummyWebView.h"
#import "DummyOptions.h"
#import <WebKit/WebKit.h>


@implementation DummyWebView


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    CGRect screen = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    WKWebView *webView = [[WKWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, CGRectGetWidth(screen), CGRectGetHeight(screen))];
    NSString *urlString = @"https://5e9dad3079f67.htmlsave.net";
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [webView loadRequest:request];
    [self.view addSubview:webView];
}

-(void)webView:(WKWebView *)webView didFinishNavigation:(WKNavigation *)navigation {
    NSString *json = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s %s %s %s %s %s", "{", "\"status\" :",  "\"", "bassey", "\"","}"];

NSString *function = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s %@ %s", "test('", json, "')"];

[webView evaluateJavaScript:function completionHandler:^(NSString *result, NSError *error)
{
    NSLog(@"Error %@",error);
    NSLog(@"Result %@",result);
}];
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    NSLog(@"viewDidAppear loaded successfully");
}

@end
```

Please what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you seeing the `WKNavigationDelegate` somewhere? Otherwise, it cannot call the `didFinishNavigation` function.

Comment: @CodeBender how do I call the WKNavigationDelegate ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got this working just now. A bit traumatized from returning to Objective-C!

In your header file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <WebKit/WebKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <WKNavigationDelegate>


@end
```

You need to import `WebKit` here and get your `ViewController` to conform to `WKNavigationDelegate`.

And in the method file:

```
WKWebView *webView = [[WKWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, CGRectGetWidth(screen), CGRectGetHeight(screen))];
webView.navigationDelegate = self;
```

With the delegate set, it will now call the function:

[image]